# Are appending and deleting faster in python using the GPU (with CUDA)?

Tags: python, performance, gpu

I'm simulating [war card games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_(card_game)), but I need very high performance. I actually use Cython and the multiprocessing module. It's actually quite fast (~33000 wars/s) with my i7 6700. I believe that it's fast because python store the reference of the objects in the list and not the data directly (such as in C and others). If I'm wrong I could still use numpy arrays instead.

The program can be highly parallelized. (And it is with the multi-process
 version).
Could a GPU version of the code speed up the program which is basically just comparing numbers and appending/deleting to lists? I've a gtx1060 6GB.

I do all the data processing at the same time as simulating the data so the data mustn't be stored in a database, all operate in the RAM. Very few RAM is requested so I think that 6GB is enough. So we don't need to send any data trough the pcie bus (except the plots for the charts).

#### Here is the code in question: (without the multiprocessing for simplicity)

```
class Battle:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nb_trick = 0
        self.escarmoucheDepth = 0
        self.player1 = []
        self.player2 = []
        self.distribute()
        self.base_deck = (tuple(self.player1), tuple(self.player2))

    def distribute(self):
        """distribute the deck to the 2 players"""
        deck = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
                5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
        np.random.shuffle(deck)
        self.player1 = deck[:26]
        self.player2 = deck[26:]

    def escarmouche(self):
        """when both players have the same card"""
        self.escarmoucheDepth = 0
        try:
            while self.player1[self.escarmoucheDepth] == self.player2[self.escarmoucheDepth]:
                self.escarmoucheDepth += 2
            if self.player1[self.escarmoucheDepth] > self.player2[self.escarmoucheDepth]:
                redistribute(self.player1, self.player2, self.escarmoucheDepth)
            elif self.player2[self.escarmoucheDepth] > self.player1[self.escarmoucheDepth]:
                redistribute(self.player2, self.player1, self.escarmoucheDepth)
        except IndexError:
            self.player1 = []
            self.player2 = []

    def trick(self):
        while self.player1 and self.player2:
            self.nb_trick += 1
            if self.player2[0] > self.player1[0]:
                self.player2.append(self.player1[0])
                self.player2.append(self.player2[0])
                del self.player1[0]
                del self.player2[0]
            elif self.player1[0] > self.player2[0]:
                self.player1.append(self.player2[0])
                self.player1.append(self.player1[0])
                del self.player1[0]
                del self.player2[0]
            else:
                self.escarmouche()
        if self.nb_trick > 10000:
            print("Infinite War?")
            return 4, self.nb_trick, tuple(self.base_deck)
        elif len(self.player2) <= 0 < len(self.player1):
            return 1, self.nb_trick, tuple(self.base_deck)
        elif len(self.player1) <= 0 < len(self.player2):
            return 2, self.nb_trick, tuple(self.base_deck)
        elif len(self.player2) <= 0 and len(self.player1) <= 0:
            return 3, self.nb_trick, tuple(self.base_deck)


def redistribute(winner, looser, depth):
    """redistribute the cards after an escarmouche"""
    for i in range(depth+1):
        winner.append(looser[0])
        winner.append(winner[0])
        del winner[0]
        del looser[0]
```

#### Recap

- Are appending and deleting faster in python using my GPU?
- If yes, then do I need to write directly CUDA code for the GPU or is there any easiest solutions?
- If python isn't appropriated to do this sort of things could you please let me know what could be better. I could build an extension with another programming language and use python as a scripting language.
- Are numpy arrays better than lists for this use case? I heard than when you compile, numpy array are faster than lists for appending.

If you need more information feel free to ask!

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Python version: 3.5

Project on GitHub: https://github.com/ZeeGabByte/War-cards-game-simulation/tree/master
(There is a Wiki in french in case you need it).

PS: I'm relatively new to Python.

Comment: @Nuageux: Not on Python 3.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It's on python 3. Do you mean that python isn't good for that? Then what do you suggest?